# Loop through dataset by row number

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a online dataset that I am looping through to save it to a sqlite database. It works well, however the 'count' in which it is sequentially looping through is based on the ID column, however there are instances where the IDs (for the category that I am filtering on) are not sequential. I'd rather loop through row number or similar if possible - but I can't seem to find a way to do it. Below is my code:

Note the count starts at 793 because this is the ID of the first 'surface' categorised record

```
private async void updateAssetRegisterLocal()
        {
            try
            {
                var current = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;

                if (current != NetworkAccess.Internet)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("No Internet Connectivity", "Move to a location with mobile coverage and try again", "OK");
                }

                else
                {

                    UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading();

                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                    var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://XXXX.azurewebsites.net/api/assets");

                    var onlineAssets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssetRegister>>(response);

                    var assetsPrelim = onlineAssets
                    .Where(w => w.Asset_Category == "Surface")
                    .OrderBy(d => d.ID)
                    .ToList();
                    ;

                    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            conn.DropTable<AssetRegister>();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            await DisplayAlert("Unsuccessful", "Can't Access", "OK");
                        }
                    }

                    for (int count = 793; count <= (assetsPrelim.Count + 793); count++)
                    {
                        var assets = assetsPrelim.Where(x => x.ID == count);
                        var id = assets.Select(l => l.ID).FirstOrDefault();
                        var asset_ID = assets.Select(l => l.Asset_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                        var road_ID = assets.Select(l => l.Road_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                        var segmentString = assets.Select(l => l.AssetSegmentString).FirstOrDefault();
                        var hierarchy = assets.Select(l => l.Road_Hierarchy).FirstOrDefault();
                        var assetCategory = assets.Select(l => l.Asset_Category).FirstOrDefault();
                        var lat = assets.Select(l => l.Lat).FirstOrDefault();
                        var inspectionDue = assets.Select(l => l.Inspection_Due).FirstOrDefault();
                        var lon = assets.Select(l => l.Lon).FirstOrDefault();
                        var stdRoadId = assets.Select(l => l.StdRoadID).FirstOrDefault();
                        var assetType = assets.Select(l => l.Asset_Type).FirstOrDefault();
                        var inspectionDate = assets.Select(l => l.Last_Inspection_Date).FirstOrDefault();

                        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
                        {
                            con.CreateTable<AssetRegister>();
                            var assetsLocal = con.Table<AssetRegister>().ToList();

                            int arlID = assetsLocal.Count + 1;

                            AssetRegister arl = new AssetRegister()
                            {
                                ID = id,
                                Asset_ID = asset_ID,
                                Asset_Type = assetType,
                                Asset_Category = assetCategory,
                                Road_ID = road_ID,
                                Road_Hierarchy = hierarchy,
                                AssetSegmentString = segmentString,
                                Inspection_Due = inspectionDue,
                                StdRoadID = stdRoadId,
                                Lat = lat,
                                Lon = lon,
                                Last_Inspection_Date = inspectionDate,

                            };

                            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.FilePath))
                            {
                                conn.CreateTable<AssetRegister>();
                                int rowsAdded = conn.Insert(arl);
                                conn.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    await DisplayAlert("Success", "Asset Register Updated on Device", "OK");
                    UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
                }
            }

            catch
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Could not get data - Report to System Adminstrator", "OK");
                UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
            }
        }
```

Comment: So you get a data set with a bunch of ids, could be 1000 of them ranging between 5 and 2000, with gaps all over the place, you want to insert only those with id higher than 793?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can loop simply iterating using `foreach`
Instead of

```
for (int count = 793; count <= (assetsPrelim.Count + 793); count++)
{
  var assets = assetsPrelim.Where(x => x.ID == count);
  var id = assets.Select(l => l.ID).FirstOrDefault();
  var asset_ID = assets.Select(l => l.Asset_ID).FirstOrDefault();
  var road_ID = assets.Select(l => l.Road_ID).FirstOrDefault();
  var segmentString = assets.Select(l => l.AssetSegmentString).FirstOrDefault();
  var hierarchy = assets.Select(l => l.Road_Hierarchy).FirstOrDefault();
  var assetCategory = assets.Select(l => l.Asset_Category).FirstOrDefault();
  var lat = assets.Select(l => l.Lat).FirstOrDefault();
  var inspectionDue = assets.Select(l => l.Inspection_Due).FirstOrDefault();
  var lon = assets.Select(l => l.Lon).FirstOrDefault();
  var stdRoadId = assets.Select(l => l.StdRoadID).FirstOrDefault();
  var assetType = assets.Select(l => l.Asset_Type).FirstOrDefault();
  var inspectionDate = assets.Select(l => l.Last_Inspection_Date).FirstOrDefault();
  ...
```

you can have

```
foreach (var asset in assetsPrelim)
{
  var id = asset.ID;
  var asset_ID = asset.Asset_ID;
  var road_ID = assets.Road_ID;
  var segmentString = asset.AssetSegmentString;
  var hierarchy = asset.Road_Hierarchy;
  var assetCategory = asset.Asset_Category;
  var lat = asset.Lat;
  var inspectionDue = asset.Inspection_Due;
  var lon = asset.Lon;
  var stdRoadId = asset.StdRoadID;
  var assetType = asset.Asset_Type;
  var inspectionDate = asset.Last_Inspection_Date;
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this one @Quercus. It's much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `foreach()` instead of `for()` loop,

```
for (var asset in assetsPrelim)
{
  var id = asset.Id;
  var asset_ID = asset.Asset_ID;
  var road_ID = assets.Road_ID;

  //...
   
}
```